# local .mdf database connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been trying to make a address book with a local .mdf database but I can't find any working connection strings.

My current connection string

```
Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Database=Database;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

When I try to open the connection I get and exception saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\******\Documents\Programmming\C#\Projects\Address Book Sql\Address
>   Book Sql\bin\Debug\Database.mdf" failed with the operating system
>   error 5(Access is denied.).
>
> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\*******
>   \Documents\Programmming\C#\Projects\Address Book Sql\Address Book
>   Sql\bin\Debug\Database.mdf' as database 'Database'.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you try giving `full control` for `everyone` user on this database file?

Answer (score 0):

**Fast solution**

Try to run your Visual Studio as Administrator.
Right click on the Visual Studio icon -> Run as administrator

**Another solution**

Check the permissions on the folder "C:\Users******\Documents\Programmming\C#\Projects\Address Book Sql\Address Book Sql\bin\Debug\"

Comment: Nothing suspicious with the permissions, I'm always running VS as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you close the connection to your .mdf from the Server Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You could install SQL Server LocalDB and host the mdf so that you don't have to worry about the path in the connection string. Hosting mdfs in LocalDB can be done through command or through code.
Its easier to manage the permissions as well.

Comment: Is the software called "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Express"?

Comment: Search for "SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB" you can install localDB on its own without installing the full blown SQL Server.